# Remove the p4 tag synonym for perforce and add it as a tag for the P4 programming language

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tag-disambiguation

While P4 might be a common acronym for Perforce, there also exists a [P4 programming language](http://p4.org/).

From the [Wikipedia page about the language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P4_%28programming_language%29):

> P4 is a programming language designed to allow programming of packet forwarding dataplanes.

Having [p4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p4) be a synonym for [perforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perforce) makes it very hard to correctly tag questions regarding the P4 programming language. Maybe it's time to remove the synonym and recreate it as its own tag for the P4 language?

I just added the [p4-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p4-language), maybe that is better than removing the synonym?

Comment: Is P4 even used? Almost anybody can define a language, many people can write an interpreter, but getting actual users for your language is another matter. I was surprised to see no Notability claims on the Wikipedia Talk page

Answer (score 3):

Let's not. "p4" was firmly established as a term for Perforce for ~20 years before this language came along. Allowing it to be used for the language would be highly confusing.

<sub>Kids these days. Doesn't anybody see if names are *used* before picking them for a project any more?</sub>